# PHONE_STATE and NEW_OUTGOING_CALL receiver confusing behaviour

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver

> Yes there are questions already asked on this topic on `Stack-Overflow;` Explored many questions, Even i am aware of `CALL_STATES`, But this is a class apart from those all, I have tried on my own from two days, finally i am decided to ask experts here...

---

This is my broadcastReceiver in service :

```
private BroadcastReceiver mCallBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver()
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        Log.d("RECEIVER X: ", "IS UP AGAIN....");
        String action = intent.getAction();

        if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL"))
        {
            // Outgoing call
            String OutGoingPhoneNumber = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);
            Log.d("RECEIVER X: ", "Outgoing Number - "+OutGoingPhoneNumber);
        }
        else if(action.equalsIgnoreCase("android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE"))
        {
            // Incoming call
            String state = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
            String InComingPhoneNumber;

            if(state == null)
            {
                InComingPhoneNumber = "UNKNOWN";
            }
            else if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING))
            {
                InComingPhoneNumber = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
                Log.d("RECEIVER X: ","Incoming number - "+InComingPhoneNumber);
            }
        }
    }
};
```

---

From `onCreate` of service i have registered receiver and its working and getting called whenever `NEW_OUTGOING_CALL` or `PHONE_STATE` events are triggered by system.

```
IntentFilter CallFilter = new IntentFilter();
CallFilter.addAction("android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE");
CallFilter.addAction("android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL");
this.registerReceiver(mCallBroadcastReceiver, CallFilter);
```

My `onStartCommand` is :

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
{
    Log.d("WatchMan : ", "\nmCallBroadcastReceiver Listening....");
    //return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    return START_STICKY;
}
```

and unregistered it from onDestroy :

```
@Override
public void onDestroy()
{
    this.unregisterReceiver(mCallBroadcastReceiver);
    Log.d("WatchMan : ", "\nDestroyed....");
    Log.d("WatchMan : ", "\nWill be created again....");
}
```

It is registered receiver and register is working even on reboot as `BOOT_COMPLETED` receiver starts this foreground service with proper notification too...

1. on android 4.2 it prints outgoing number and in oreo it prints outgoing number blank..
2. On some changes Oreo Prints outgoing number but stops getting Incoming number when state is `EXTRA_STATE_RINGING`
3. sometimes It prints Outgoing number twice

> I want incoming phone number while `EXTRA_STATE_RINGING` I want `NEW_OUTGOING_CALL` outgoing phone number only once, and when the STATE `EXTRA_STATE_IDLE` means call is ended i want to start a new service. also it should work on Oreo and in android 4.2 Any help will be appreciated and thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Above `Marshmallow` it requires only `Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE` runtime permission BUT Above Oreo `Manifest.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS` also required in runtime.

Code is now working :

```
private BroadcastReceiver mCallBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver()
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        Log.d("RECEIVER X: ", "IS UP AGAIN....");
        String action = intent.getAction();
        String PhoneNumber = "UNKNOWN";

        if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL"))
        {
            PhoneNumber = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);
            Log.d("RECEIVER X: ", "Outgoing number : " + PhoneNumber);
            Intent InsertDb = new Intent(context, CatchNumbers.class);
            InsertDb.putExtra("TYPE", "OUTGOING");
            InsertDb.putExtra("PHONENUMBER", PhoneNumber);
            startService(InsertDb);
        }
        if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE"))
        {
            if (intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE).equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING))
            {
                PhoneNumber = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
                Log.d("RECEIVER X: ", "Incoming number : " + PhoneNumber);
                Intent InsertDb = new Intent(context, CatchNumbers.class);
                InsertDb.putExtra("TYPE", "INCOMING");
                InsertDb.putExtra("PHONENUMBER", PhoneNumber);
                startService(InsertDb);
            }
            if (intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE).equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE))
            {
                Log.d("RECEIVER X: ", "CALL ENDED... ");
                // start service to send SMS now from Table
                Intent InsertDb = new Intent(context, CatchNumbers.class);
                InsertDb.putExtra("TYPE", "CALLEND");
                startService(InsertDb);
            }
            if (intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE).equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK))
            {
                Log.d("RECEIVER X: ", "ACTIVE OUTGOING CALL : ");
            }
        }
    }
};
```

---

> Hope it helps someone... like me